# How to finish off Expander template?

Tags: wpf, styles, expander

In my bid to try and learn some more about WPF I've been looking at some styling of controls, and I'm hoping someone can help me with some animation.

What I've been trying to do is to take an Expander, make it animate it's expand/collapse and to do this automatically on mouseover.

I've found too websites illustrating these techniques separately but I'm struggling to combine them and hoping someone can help me finish off. At the moment I can't get the animation working and am not sure why.

[Animation](http://mattserbinski.com/blog/animating-expander)
[AutoExpansion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/355c0081-8f63-4382-be01-b3aab43647a6/)

I've stripped down much of the animation styling to something more simple, as I don't need the complex example for learning.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="640" Height="480">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="Timeline1">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:0.25" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.25" Value="1"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="Timeline2">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.45" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.45" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Border x:Name="border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" 
                                                        Visibility="Visible" 
                                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                        Focusable="False" 
                                                        x:Name="HeaderSite" 
                                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
                                                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" 
                                                        DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Focusable="false" 
                                                            Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                            x:Name="ExpandSite" 
                                                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                                            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                                    <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="0"/>
                                            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Timeline1}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Timeline2}"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Green" Width="100" Header="" x:Name="expander" Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle1}" IsExpanded="True">
            <ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" x:Name="listBox">
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="ListBoxItem"/>
            </ListBox>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Style trigger. Here you go:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Expander.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Expander.IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" />
</Expander>
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but if I try to add this to the template it doesn't work. If I add to the expander itself I get a "Style property has already been set on expander".

Comment: Definately put it on the Expander. If you get the "already set" then it means you probably have <Expander Style="" /> which conflicts. Just move your style business to <Style><Setter /> tags next to the <Style.Triggers>. Trust me, this is the solution. I updated my answer to show you the <Setter/> stuff I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example of what you're trying to do:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Expander Name="theExpander">
        <Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock Text="Foo" />
                <TextBlock Text="Bar" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=theExpander, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBlock Text="Baz" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander.Header>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Now obviously it's not perfect, but I'm using it to illustrate how you can bind visibility to an object to IsExpanded so that it gets the "collapsing" effect you're after. The problem of course is that the expander button isn't aligned properly and visually I'm sure it's not exactly what you're after, but all you have to do is grab the Expander template from the [Microsoft Expander Style and Templates page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and override the specific bit you need.

If you still have problems post a follow-up here and I'll have a go at it myself for you.